The styles of Primeng are not effective in the older version of Google Chrome
When I use a relatively newer version of Primeng with an old version of Google Chrome, its styles completely fail to apply. Updating Google Chrome or downgrading Primeng resolves this issue. Here is a screenshot of the behavior when I open the official Primeng example with an old browser version.
enter image description here
I tested the compatibility between Google Chrome and the version of Primeng.
enter image description here
What configuration or changes do I need to make to ensure that the new version of Primeng components display correctly in older browsers?

Primeng version 16.4.0 has introduced a breaking change with the use of new CSS feature: CSS Cascading layer, which caused old Google Chrome browser (Chrome <= 98) UI to break.
Unfortunately, there's no workaround other than sticking with version 16.3.1 for now. Browser support for cascading layer can be seen here: https://caniuse.com/css-cascade-layers.
You can also check this Github issue for more info: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/13757
